# join and group by not working properly in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have a blog with 2 table. First `posts` table with a key `category_id` and `categories` table. In a page I want to show all categories with count of their posts. I write this query but it have a problem. It did not show categories with no posts. in other word categories with 0 posts did not appear in the results.

And can you help to write this in eloquent system in laravel

```
SELECT categories.* , Count(posts.total) as total
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * , COUNT(*) as total from posts GROUP By posts.id
) as posts
ON posts.category_id = categories.id
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect your outer `COUNT` to do when you don't have an outer `GROUP BY`?  Also, you should get in a habit of explicitly selecting your columns instead of using `*` so that you can follow the SQL standard of only selecting columns that are either aggregate functions (such as `COUNT`) or are listed in your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:

```
SELECT categories.* , IFNULL(Count(posts.id),0) as total
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN 
posts
ON posts.category_id = categories.id 
Group by categories.id;
```